# Is the universe expanding on a preferred axis, or asymmetrically?

Tags: universe, space-expansion

I remember back in 2011 i found this paper on the research a team of Chinese physicist completed about the universe may having a prefered axis when expanding. 
[On ARXIV](http://arxiv.org/PS_cache/arxiv/pdf/1109/1109.0941v4.pdf)

I haven't seen any other papers released on the same topic and i'm wondering if any new evidence or papers have been released since then. Or if anyone has some information on it that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This paper on the Arxiv](http://arxiv.org/abs/1406.6448) claims to have measured an anisotropy at the $2\sigma$ level. I'm not familiar enough with the subject to pass judgement, though I get the impression that the general view is *interesting but unproven* at the moment. If nothing else the paper gives a convenient literature review.

Various anisotropies have been suggested, such as a north-south anisotropy in the fine structure constant and the [axis of evil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_microwave_background#Low_multipoles_and_other_anomalies) alignment of low multipoles in the CMB data. However the various proposed anisotropies don't line up with each other, which strengthens the skeptics case.

Comment: Thankyou John! Will be interesting in the coming years to see any new evidence to back this case.